# Meaning of the Pali-word "sampajanasi"?

Tags: theravada

In the *Parayanavagga*,Gatha #93, the Buddha says to Dhotaka: "Yam kinci **sampajanasi**"

What is the exact meaning of the word *sampajanasi* ?

Comment: [Sampajāna](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.3:1:3589.pali.1879131)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to 'know' or have an intelligent understanding of something as being true. So when the Buddha says "yam kinci sampajanasi..." it means "whatever you know...".

Comment: Here is a version of the text with English and Pali side-by-side   https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Texts-and-Translations/Parayanavagga/Parayanavaggo.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Having a clear understanding is the meaning of that